# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while adding Wazuh repository

Tags: ubuntu, curl, wazuh, ossec, apt-key

I'm trying to add the Wazuh repository to download the official Wazuh packages as instructed in [their documentation page](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/wazuh-agent/wazuh-agent-package-linux.html) in an Ubuntu VM.

When I run the command specified in their documentation page:

```
sudo curl -s https://packages.wazuh.com/key/GPG-KEY-WAZUH | sudo apt-key add -
```

I am met with the following error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Keep in mind I have already found a solution for this issue and I want to share it with anyone else that might be facing the same issue.

I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the required key file was not found. Therefore, adding it using the following command solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-key add GPG-KEY-WAZUH
```

Here is the full command to download the official Wazuh packages:

```
sudo curl -s https://packages.wazuh.com/key/GPG-KEY-WAZUH | sudo apt-key add GPG-KEY-WAZUH
```

Note: Make sure to run the above command in the root directory of the Wazuh repository

Answer (score 0):

use http instead of https

```
sudo curl -s http://packages.wazuh.com/key/GPG-KEY-WAZUH | sudo apt-key add -
```